# Share multiple images with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to share multiple images with UIActivityViewController, but so far, the examples I have found only share 1 image at a time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do this using:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"];    
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image1, image2] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: How about images: [UIImage] = [image1, image2]. Then put the images to UIActivityViewController. I try this way, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should make a separate SO question for that

Answer (score -2):

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imagesForClients, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Where `imagesForClients` is an array of UIImage objects.